# Error C2059 While defining max() function

Tags: c, error-handling, syntax-error

I'm getting:

```
Error   1   error C2059: syntax error : 'type'  c:\users\user\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\ex4\q4\tree.h   40  1   Q4
Error   2   error C2059: syntax error : 'type'  c:\users\user\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\ex4\q4\tree.c   174 1   Q4
```

`max()` is at the bottom of tree.c

Here's tree.h:

```
#ifndef __TREE_H
#define __TREE_H

/***** Type definitions *****/

typedef struct TreeNode{ 
    int data; 
    struct TreeNode* left; 
    struct TreeNode* right; 
} TreeNode; 
typedef struct tree{ 
    TreeNode* root; 
} Tree;

/****** Prototypes *****/

/* Testing trees */
Tree testTreeCase1();
Tree testTreeCase2();
Tree testTreeCase3();
Tree testTreeCase4();
Tree testTreeCase5();

/* This function creates a new node */
TreeNode* createNewTreeNode(int data, TreeNode *left, TreeNode *right);
/* This function deallocates a given tree */
void freeTree(Tree *tr);
void freeTreeHelper(TreeNode *root);
/* This function returns the number of nodes of a given tree */
int numNodes(Tree *tr);
int numNodesHelper(TreeNode *root);

/* This function returns the sum of all of the nodes data of a given tree */
int sumNodes(Tree *tr);
int sumNodesHelper(TreeNode *root);

int height(Tree *tr);
int heightHelper(TreeNode *root);

int max(int a, int b);
#endif
```

and here's tree.c:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "tree.h"

/* This function creates a new node */
TreeNode* createNewTreeNode(int data, TreeNode *left, TreeNode *right)
{
    TreeNode *res;
    res = (TreeNode*)malloc(sizeof(TreeNode));
    res->data = data;
    res->left = left;
    res->right = right;
    return res;
}
/* Shell function for numNodes() */
int numNodes(Tree *tr)
{
    return numNodesHelper(tr->root);
}
/* This function returns the number of nodes of a given tree's root node */
int numNodesHelper(TreeNode *root)
{
    int numNodesLeft, numNodesRight;

    if (root == NULL)
        return 0;

    else
    {
        numNodesLeft = numNodesHelper(root->left);
        numNodesRight = numNodesHelper(root->right);
        return numNodesLeft + numNodesRight + 1;
    }
}
/* Shell function for sumNodes() */
int sumNodes(Tree *tr)
{
    return sumNodesHelper(tr->root);
}
/* This function returns the sum of all of the nodes data of a given tree's root node */
int sumNodesHelper(TreeNode *root)
{
    int sumNodesLeft, sumNodesRight;

    if (root == NULL)
        return 0;

    else
    {
        sumNodesLeft = sumNodesHelper(root->left);
        sumNodesRight = sumNodesHelper(root->right);
        return sumNodesLeft + sumNodesRight + root->data;
    }
}
/* Shell function for freeTree() */
void freeTree(Tree *tr)
{
    freeTreeHelper(tr->root);
    tr->root = NULL;
}
/* This function deallocates a given tree's root node */
void freeTreeHelper(TreeNode *root)
{
    if (root == NULL)
        return;

    else if (root->left == NULL && root->right == NULL)
        free(root);

    else
    {
        freeTreeHelper(root->right);
        freeTreeHelper(root->left);
        free(root);
    }
}
/* Shell function for heightHelper() */
int height (Tree *tr) 
{
    return heightHelper(tr->root);
}
/* This function returns the height of a given tree's root node */
int heightHelper(TreeNode *root)
{
    int heightLeft, heightRight;

    if (root == NULL) // case empty tree
        return -1;

    else if (root->left == NULL && root->right == NULL)
        return 0;

    else if (root->left == NULL)
        return 1 + heightHelper(root->right);

    else if (root->right == NULL)
        return 1+ heightHelper(root->left);

    else
    {
        heightLeft = heightHelper(root->left);
        heightRight = heightHelper(root->right);
        return 1 + (heightLeft>heightRight?heightLeft:heightRight);
    }
}

// Checking trees according to special cases 
/* Case 1: Empty tree */
Tree testTreeCase1()
{

    Tree resTree;
    resTree.root = NULL;
    return resTree;

}
/* Case 2: Only root node */
Tree testTreeCase2()
{
    Tree resTree;
    TreeNode  *root;

    root = createNewTreeNode(1, NULL, NULL);
    resTree.root = root;

    return resTree;
}
/* Case 3: Only right sub-tree exists */
Tree testTreeCase3()
{
    Tree resTree;
    TreeNode  *root, *l1_r, *l2_rr, *l2_rl;

    l2_rl = createNewTreeNode(4, NULL, NULL);
    l2_rr = createNewTreeNode(3, NULL, NULL);
    l1_r = createNewTreeNode(2, l2_rl, l2_rr);
    root = createNewTreeNode(1, NULL, l1_r);
    resTree.root = root;

    return resTree;
}
/* Case 4: Only left sub-tree exists */
Tree testTreeCase4()
{
    Tree resTree;
    TreeNode  *root, *l1_l, *l2_lr, *l2_ll;

    l2_ll = createNewTreeNode(4, NULL, NULL);
    l2_lr = createNewTreeNode(3, NULL, NULL);
    l1_l = createNewTreeNode(2, l2_ll, l2_lr);
    root = createNewTreeNode(1, l1_l, NULL);
    resTree.root = root;

    return resTree;
}
/* Case 5: Both left and right sub-trees exists */
Tree testTreeCase5()
{
    Tree resTree;
    TreeNode  *root, *l1_r, *l1_l, *l2_lr, *l2_ll, *l2_rr, *l2_rl;

    l2_ll = createNewTreeNode(7, NULL, NULL);
    l2_lr = createNewTreeNode(6, NULL, NULL);
    l2_rl = createNewTreeNode(5, NULL, NULL);
    l2_rr = createNewTreeNode(4, NULL, NULL);
    l1_l = createNewTreeNode(2, l2_ll, l2_lr);
    l1_r = createNewTreeNode(3, l2_rl, l2_rr);
    root = createNewTreeNode(1, l1_l, l1_r);
    resTree.root = root;

    return resTree;
}

int max(int a, int b)
{
    return a>b ? a:b;
}
```

Comment: Nobody will be scrolling through this to help you since you did not make any assumptions of your own. Isolate the code that we should review, make an assumption of the error and *possibly* someone will help you. Right now it looks like you have done nothing to solve this on your own.

Comment: @JacobPollack, What's there to solve? The error pops up the minute I define `max()` function. Without it the code complies flawlessly. I wrote that the function is written in the bottom of tree.c because I knew nobody likes to waste their time, but I chose to post all of tree.h and tree.c since last time I asked a question I was asked to paste the whole files. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @JacobPollack, for what it's worth, I don't even understand the error, what does a syntax error called 'type' even means?

Comment: Rename the function from `max` to `my_max` in both the interface and C source file.

Comment: It works, thanks. Why was it happening? Is `max` a reserved word in C?

Comment: I have added a slightly more detailed explanation as an answer for everyone below. For your next SO post please state an assumption so we can correct you... otherwise we are just telling you the answer. I am happy to help but it's much better for you if you state your own assumptions (even better if they're wrong so we can correct your thinking).

Comment: If you can edit your question to change anything (add a space or something) so that I can remove my down vote then that would be awesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `max` is likely reserved in another library that you have used. This is a common issue when working on large applications in C. The solution is to rename your function from `max` to `my_max` (or remove the library that has already reserved `max`).

Comment: I actually only use `stdlib`, `stdio` and `tree.h` which is mine. argh